# ReactJS - Multi-page app not working after being built for production

Tags: reactjs, react-router, hosting

I have a multi-page app that I am trying to host on GoDaddy. After running `npm build`, I upload the files to GoDaddy as per their instructions and I am able to view my homepage without any trouble. When I try to navigate to another page such as the about page, I get a 404 error.

I have been searching and the solutions I attempted did not work. I tried adding `"homepage": "http://www.kashy.com.au/",` to my `package.json`. I also tried playing with the routes. (Adding the URL for the site in the path).

I am new to React and so I don't quite understand how the routes work. Could someone point me in the right direction for solving this problem?

Comment: What URL are you hoping to navigate to, and what URL do you actually go to? That information will help people debug your problem, I think.

Comment: @KenY-N I have updated my question with the actual URL for you to have a look at. I am trying to navigate to the about page which in my head should be http://www.kashy.ccom.au/about which is where the browser goes, just gives a 404 though.

Comment: The 404 page should also have a URL, or look at your browser's debug window, Network panel to see where the redirection is. BTW, that URL has `ccom`. not `com` - is that just a typo in the comment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to redirect all urls to ur site on Godaddy to point to the homepage/index as the routing is handled by your client/react app.

Create an .htaccess file to redirect all requests to index.html.

Sample

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

Steps

- From your cpanel file manager, go to the root folder of your website (ie. public_html).
- Create the (dot)htaccess file, by clicking on the top left menu
- Right click on the file and edit and then paste the above
- Save

Comment: Should the ht access file have a specific name and where do I reference it?

Comment: Im assuming you are hosting on GoDaddy.
https://www.godaddy.com/help/what-is-htaccess-2504

Comment: Added steps for adding it to Godaddy